# transform.localposition has a huge delay

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm moving my player using with an animation and I'm using a parent gameobject to move the player. But when I'm updating the transform.localposition in the script it has a huge delay. It takes about 1 second before the object actually goes to the localposition I set it to in the script. Can anyone help me solving this issue?

```
private Animator anim;
private bool anim_Started;
private bool anim_Finished;
// Use this for initialization

void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}


void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
        anim_Started = true;
        anim_Finished = false;
        anim.Play("MoveUp");
    }
}

void AnimationFinished() {
    anim_Finished = true;
}

void LateUpdate() {
    if (anim_Finished & anim_Started){
        transform.parent.position = transform.position;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        anim_Started = false;
        anim_Finished = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is AnimationFinished bound?

Comment: I just guess that you wanted to say `if (!anim_Finished & anim_Started)`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue. It was really simple and stupid. I called the AnimationFinished method inside of the animation but my animation wasn't ended when I called it. That's why the localposition wouldn't update, It was waiting for the animation to finish.